# How can I get the original UI / look of the android Switch widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

Under Android 4.x, my switch widgets looked like this:

[image: Switch widget, API 15]

Under 5.1, it looks like this:

[image: Switch widget, API 21]

Setting ShowText="true" didn't help much:

[image]

Is there a way to get the old behavior back? I don't want to have to implement my own switch widget, but I will if necessary.

Comment: Look into your sdk folders. You'll find the used resources (mine are in `C:\Program Files\Adt-Bundle\sdk\platforms\android-1#\data\res\drawable-hdpi` and other densities - being **#** between 6 and 9). import those ones to your project. Change your styles or themes to use your app resources instead of Android's default ones. Don't forget to import the `drawable` xmls as well.